# htaccess how to remove /home from URL

Tags: .htaccess

**FOLDERS:**

- **ROOT**

  - pages

    - home.php
    - contact.php
  - .htaccess

**htaccess:**

```
# Load files from pages folder 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+pages/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]

# Default index.php
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [L,R]
```

this works, but when I open **localhost:1993**, it will change the address to **localhost:1993/home**. How should I edit the htaccess so that **/home** does not appear? (only for **localhost:1993**).

**My request is:**

- **localhost:1993** redirect to **localhost:1993** (hide **/home**)
- **localhost:1993/contact** redirect to **localhost:1993/contact**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ pages/contact.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ pages/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

query version:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(.*)$ pages/$1.php?query=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```